# Inserting element in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make this program which gets an element from user and inserts it into the made array by user (array must be sorted)
But it doesn't work properly

for example:
a[4]

```
a[0]=1
a[1]=3
a[2]=5
a[3]=7
```

then i insert>> 6

but then it goes like this

```
a[0]=1
a[1]=3
a[2]=5
a[3]=6
a[4]=3866936
```

the array is able to have upto 100 elements

:|

it's a practice from a book

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

void insert(int[], int&, int);

int main()
{
    const int maxsize = 100;
    int a[maxsize];
    cout << "build ur array\n";  Sleep(650);
    cout << "Enter the number of elements:";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int k;
    cout << "Enter a new element:";
    cin >> k;
    n++;
    insert(a, n, k);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
 }



void insert(int a[], int& n, int x)
{
    for (int i = n - 1; a[i]>x; i--)
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
     for (int i = n; i <= n; i--)
     {
         if (x >= a[i])
         {
             a[i + 1] = x;
             break;
         }
     }
```

Comment: If the array has only 4 elements you cannot make it have 5 elements. The C++ way of doing it is to use `std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(6);` and let the standard library worry about annoying pointer fiddling.

Comment: you are saying 4 elements, but the code shows you have an array of 100. int a[maxsize];

Comment: You'll have problems with inserting a number smaller than those already in the array, and you don't need the second loop in `insert` (the location you want is where the first loop stopped - you don't need to search again).

Comment: @lakesh that's not the problem

Comment: @nwp but the array can have upto 100 elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know what you're doing ex. no one can enter more than 99, assuming you will check if the value is less than 100, you have only one error in insert:

```
a[i] = a[i+1];
```

should be

```
a[i+1] = a[i];
```

The full function should look like this to work with all possible cases:

```
void insert(int a[], int& n, int x)
{
    for (int i = n - 2; a[i]>x && i >= 0; i--)
        a[i+1] = a[i];
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (x >= a[i])
        {
            a[i + 1] = x;
            return;
        }
    }
    a[0] = x;
}
```

Comment: +1. (It seems you're the only one who read the code and answered the actual question rather than just repeating the "use std::vector" mantra.)

Comment: im not sure but i think they are same
my edit works in any case too
but im not sure
tnx

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing undefined behavior due to the fact that you are reading from outside of the array bounds (`0 - 3`). You should use an `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(3);
vec.push_back(5);
vec.push_back(7);
```

and then:

```
vec.push_back(6);
```

Later on, if you want to sort the array you can just do:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Or if he doesn't have knowledge or experience with vectors, I'd recommend just making a grow() function. Clearly vectors are the way to go though.

Comment: @WhyCry You think learning how to write a correct `grow()` function is easier that learning to use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

With some stuff from STL, you may use the following:

```
class SortedVector
{
public:
    using const_iterator = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;

    void insert(int value) {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), value);
        v.insert(it, value);
    }

    const_iterator begin() const { return v.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return v.end(); }

private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/iwaHxv)

- `std::vector` is the container.
- `std::lower_bound` finds the location where to insert (the way that insertion is still in order)
- `std::vector::insert` does the insertion (which the shifting of the element).

if you don't want to use std::vector and us C-array: you may use:

```
void insert(int a[], int& n, int x)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(a, a + n, x);
    std::copy(it, a + n, it + 1);
    *it = x;
    ++n;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/4pLKam).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remember that index of array starts from 0. When you want to have 4 elements array `int tab[4]` you can can read/write elements value using indexes from 0 to 3 `tab[0], tab[1], tab[2], tab[3]`. Element `tab[4]` is not part of your array and when you want to read element from your such place, you will get value that is already there (you can think about it as unpredictable random value, but it is not true random value).

By the way, you question is about C language. If you using C++, read about containers like `std::array`, `std::vector` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> > >
> >     with help of prajmus
> >     i solved the problem
> >     :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

void insert(int[], int&, int);

int main()
{
const int maxsize = 100;
int a[maxsize];
cout << "build ur array\n";  Sleep(650);
cout << "Enter the number of elements:";
int n;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "a[" << i << "]=";
    cin >> a[i];
}
int k;
cout << "Enter a new element:";
cin >> k;
n++;
insert(a, n, k);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] << endl;
system("pause");
}



void insert(int a[], int& n, int x)
 {
 for (int i = n - 2; a[i]>x; i--)
    a[i+1] = a[i];

for (int i = n-1; i <= n; i--)
{
    if (x >= a[i])
    {   a[i + 1] = x;
        break;
}
}
 }
```

Comment: Actually it does not work if the element is less than the first or bigger than the last one, check my edit

Comment: well the array most be sorted 
from small to bigger

Comment: I know, but imagine you have [2,3,4,5] and insert [0] or [6], it won't work then.

Comment: it actually works in most of case even not sorted but ur edit is surely   better